# Close the pop up that opens if you open another pop up

Tags: html, css, user-interface, popup, frontend

Hy, I made several pop ups. To close the pop up by press the opened popup. I want to make if you open a new pop up then another pop up that appears is closed.

> For example if I open a pop up 1. then I open the pop up 2, then when the pop up 2 opens the pop up 1 is closed

here my html code

```
<body style="text-align:center">
<br><br><br>
<div class="popup" onclick="popUp1()">Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">Popup 1</span>
</div>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<div class="popup" onclick="popUp2()">Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">Popup 2</span>
</div>

&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<div class="popup" onclick="popUp3()">Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup3">Popup 3</span>
</div>

<script>
function popUp1() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

function popUp2() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

function popUp3() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup3");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
```

Here my css

```
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}    
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}    
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}    
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity:1 ; }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need a JavaScript function to do this, something like this:

```
 $('.popup').on('click', function() {
      $('.popup').each(function(i, elem){
          if ($(elem).hasClass('show') && this !== elem ) {
                $(elem).removeClass('show');
          }
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'll try to explain it using plain JavaScript since you're not using jQuery as on other replies.*

This code should remove all popups having the `show` class and add the `show` class to the one that has triggered the event.

```
   function closeOpenPopups (e) {
    var openpopups = document.querySelectorAll('.popup.show');
     openpopups.forEach(function(){
      this.classList.remove('show');
     });
      e.classList.add('show');
    }
    var popups = document.querySelectorAll('.popup');
```

You can add it to the onclick attribute the same way you're already doing on your HTML

```
<div class="popup" onclick="closeOpenPopups()" >
 ...
</div>
```

Hope it helps,